# Getting return type of function when specific arguments are passed in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function `versatileFn` that only cares about one property of an argument, performs some actions on the property of the argument and afterwards returns the argument.

```
const versatileFn = <T extends { someProp: number }>(arrayOfObj: T[], key: keyof T) => {
    console.log("this property defenitely exists: ",arrayOfObj[0].someProp)
    return arrayOfObj
};
```

The object that is passed can have any form as long as it provides the bare minimum of being an array of objects with the property `someProp`

```
const myArray = [{someProp: 5, someOtherProp: "ok"}]
```

When passing this array to the function, the `result` will be of type `{someProp: number; someOtherProp: string;}[]`

```
const result = versatileFn(myArray, "someProp")
```

As the typeofGenericResult will not know about the property `someOtherProp`, its type will only be `{someProp: number;}[]`

```
type typeofGenericResult = ReturnType<typeof versatileFn>
```

However, I want to know the specific ReturnType of the function when an array of type `myArray` is passed to it. Something like this:

```
type typeofSpecificResult = ReturnType<typeof versatileFn<typeof myArray>>
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: COuld you please provide some examples? I don't quite understand the question

Comment: if you copy each of the lines i posted in this exact order and execute it, it should work.

Comment: Oh, I see. TS does not work that way. Try this type: `type typeofGenericResult = typeof result;` .

Comment: But the problem is that I cannot execute the function at that time. I basically need the type before, because the array im passing in is fetched asynchronously from a server